# jQuery Datepicker - Localisation with Restricted dates

Tags: jquery, date, localization, datepicker, restriction

I have a question about setting up a jQuery Datepicker with restricted dates, and also localized to the current language.

I can successfully get the language to translate correctly, using the regional setup paramameters, and I can also get the restricted date selection working - , but not both at the same time...

I'm unsure of the correct syntax to use. This is what i have so far:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {



    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['it']);  //Set the language of all Datepickers on the page to Italian



    $( "input[id$=_30]" ).datepicker({  

    beforeShowDay: function(date) { return [date.getDay() == 1]; } //Restrict this  particular calendar to only allow Mondays to be selected 


    });

});
```

I know I have to somehow combine the two setup instructions, but I cannot get it to work, and I can't find any examples..

Please can someone help?

Thanks in advance

Ed

Answer (score 0):

I've just set up a Fiddle for it and both localization and restriction are working fine:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['it']);  
    $('#txtDate').datepicker(
    {  
        beforeShowDay: function(date) { return [date.getDay() == 1];}
    });
});
```

[Datepicker Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/2ft570va/)

This only works for a datepicker displayed in an overlay when clicking the input field, not for an inline datepicker embedded in the page. But in case you're using an overlay datepicker this should be sufficient.